# Why does Cypress’s `invoke("text")` hang and fail?

Tags: cypress

I’m using Cypress 12.17.1. My test runs `cy.contains("Mentions légales").invoke("text").should("eq", "Mentions légales")`. (silly example, I know)

In Cypress, I can see that the HTML element has been found. But the `.invoke("text")` coming next doesn’t seem to work. Cypress waits a few seconds on this instruction and returns an error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property message of [object DOMException] which has only a getter.

I can’t see a difference compared to the examples in the docs or recipes ([example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/server-communication__bootstrapping-your-app/cypress/e2e/bootstrapping_your_app_spec.cy.js)).

It’s not specific to `text` it seems, any other method I tried failed in the same way. I also used `get` to target an element, no luck. I’ve also tried many other syntaxes like:

```
  .should(($div) => {
     const text = $div.text()
     expect(text).to.match(/.*/)
  })

  .should(($div) => {
     expect($div.get(0).innerText).to.eq('foobarbaz')
  })
```

The test begins with a simple `cy.visit(…)` and I also tried following it with `cy.wait(1000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this was happening only on the website I was working on, both in my local dev environment and on the live website. I started disabling scripts and quickly noticed that this instruction here was the cause of the issue:

```
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
```

Just removing it fixed the whole thing.

I thought jQuery was exposed in Cypress as `Cypress.$` to prevent conflicts like this, but apparently it doesn’t prevent this one from happening. Luckily I wasn’t using this alias too much, so removing it was easy.

Comment: But it does not seem to be reproducible, if you check from a clean web page and add that line in a script it passes.

Comment: Weird, maybe depending on when the script is called? In my case it was from a `<script src="..." async>` in `<head>`.